# RC Debounce: Is there a benefit to placing the capacitor in parallel with the switch?

Tags: filter, debounce

I've always seen RC debounce circuits drawn wire the capacitor tied to the same potential as the switch.

E.g.

- if the switch is high-side, the cap is high-side
- if the switch is low-side, the cap is low-side.

Like this:

[image: Debounce A]

But, for a normally open switch, this has the issue of transience at boot-up. At t=0, C1 acts like a short, giving an unwanted rising edge on boot to the signal.

Is there any disadvantage to tying the capacitor to the opposite logic level as the switch? Like this:

[image: Debounce B]

Comment: Why would you ever have the cap tied high? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: For the purposes of debouncong, both configurations work well. Only the logic control and time constants are different. If you replace R1 with another but opposite switch (complementary pair), the time constants will be equal.

Comment: @DKNguyen provided that the supply is low impedance there would be no real difference apart from the psychological idea that ground is ground.  However, at power-up the capacitor will initially pull high, which may be desirable in some situations.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm in the same boat, but if you look up deboune circuits, you'll find they are almost always like the first one I presented.

This is what has me wondering: why has this seemingly become the standard RC debounce in textbooks/articles?

Comment: Only 1 image on the entire first page of Google images has a high tied cap for me. The only thing I can see is that people like to have a button press represent a HI while also liking the idea it directly discharges the cap.

Comment: Depending on which circuit you pick the effect will be different at power on. The designer may want a  specific output during the Power On sequence then default to the opposite value. Depending on the micro I see caps tied high on the reset to generate the reset pulse.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any disadvantage to tying the capacitor to the opposite logic
> level as the switch? Like this:

Yes. Now the switch is connected to the supply voltage, not ground. In some cases this may be a problem, eg. possibility of cable short from supply to ground, higher EMI due to switch not grounded, static discharge could be injected directly into supply, switch might share common connection with other parts that must go to ground.

The other alternative is to wire the capacitor to the high side. This is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that all circuit diagrams have to be layed out before production.The first diagram with the standard        pushbutton normally open              switch  will be better to lay out with the switch having a ground plane connection .This is more true when there are multiple switches.